# How to convert blocking file io to non-blocking in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, io, nonblocking

I am writing a code send the output of a terminal command over a socket in C. I have tried using select for asynchronous reading and avoid blocking the event-loop, but I wasn't successful.

How can I change this code to make the file stream IO non-blocking?

```
int maxfdpl;
fd_set rset;
char sendline[100], recvline[100], my_msg[100];
FILE *in;
char str[30]="ping 192.168.26.219";
if(!(in = popen(str, "r"))){
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
FD_ZERO(&rset);
FD_SET(fileno(in), &rset);
maxfdpl =fileno(in) + 1;
select(maxfdpl, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
while(1) {
      if (FD_ISSET(fileno(in), &rset)) {
         if (fgets(sendline, 100, in)) {
            send_over_socket(sendline);
         }
      }
}
```

How can I remove the while loop (which is blocking the event-loop) and replace the code with a non-blocking IO operation?

Answer (score 0):

```
int blockFD(int fd, int blocking)
{
    /* Save the current flags */
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1)
        return 0;

    if (blocking)
        flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
    else
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;

    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) != -1;
}
```

Returns 0 if failed.

Comment: sorry, but how can I integrate my code with yours? My code is still in the event loop, can you please help me re-write my code?

Comment: Can you explain this code a little bit? still I don't know how to use it

Comment: Considering that you are now two years a member and contributed nothing I'm sure you can manage on your own. After all, the code is pretty selfexplanatory.

Comment: I know that it changes the file descriptor to non-blocking, but how can I capture the event? P.S. I was a two year member but I have been involved in many other things: java, javascript, nodejs, ...

Comment: I mean, instead of a while I should write a listener, or something that will be called whenever the file has a new line to show. Would you help me with that? or refer me to a sample

Comment: You must use (p)select/poll to wait for the events. then you can simply check if data is available, or to be more precice, if a read or write would not block and otherwise you can continue with your regular code.

Comment: I called the function blockFD(fileno(in), 0) and then used select(..) as in my code, I removed the while loop and replaced it with if(read(...)) but it runs only once!